# replace password reset mail template with custom template laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

I did the laravel command for authentication system , `php artisan make:auth` it made the authentication system for my app and almost everything is working.

Now when i use the forgot password and it sends me a token to my mail id , i see that the template contains laravel and some other things that i might wanna edit or ommit, to be precise , i want my custom template to be used there.

I looked up at the controllers and their source files but i can't find the template or the code that is displaying the html in the mail.

How do i do it ?

How do i change it?

This is the default template that comes from laravel to the mail.
[image]

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Just a heads up: In addition to the previous answer, there are additional steps if you want to modify the ***notification lines*** like `You are receiving this...`, etc. Below is a step-by-step guide.

You'll need to [override the default](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passwords#password-customization) `sendPasswordResetNotification` method on your `User` model.

Why? Because the lines are pulled from `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword.php`. Modifying it in the core will mean your changes are lost during an update of Laravel.

To do this, add the following to your your `User` model.

```
use App\Notifications\PasswordReset; // Or the location that you store your notifications (this is default).

/**
 * Send the password reset notification.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new PasswordReset($token));
}
```

Lastly, [create that notification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#creating-notifications):

```
php artisan make:notification PasswordReset
```

And example of this notification's content:

```
/**
 * The password reset token.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $token;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($token)
{
    $this->token = $token;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}

/**
 * Build the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.') // Here are the lines you can safely override
        ->action('Reset Password', url('password/reset', $this->token))
        ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}
```

Comment: remember to translate also the subcopy or sending will fail with an undefined variable !

Comment: In the published assets where are the variables ?! I need to fully rewrite the template and I've no reference about variables to use for url, greetings, and so on

Comment: This is what I was looking for . `view('some_blade_view',compact(,,,))` can be used to define custom template and send any params we want . https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#formatting-mail-messages

Comment: By writing this `url('password/reset', $this->token)`, i am only getting the reset url with token, email is not written. How can i add the email in the reset url?

Comment: @camelCase camelCase - I need your help, kindly suggest me how can I change the ResetPassword email's html template (look & feel), not content/text of email in Laravel 8.x version? Look forward to hear you. Thanks.

Answer (score 46):

Run the following command in the terminal and the two email templates will be copied to your resources/vendor/notifications folder. Then you can modify the templates.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

You can read more about `Notifications` in Laravel [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications).

Comment: The email template will be inside resources/views/vendor/notifications folder.

Comment: I think the complete answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/41401524/2144424

Comment: Changing something in vendor directory does not seem to be a solution

Comment: @jpussacq your suggested url does not have correct solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/41401524/2144424 given solution also not describing how to change the logo in email. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

If you wish to modify the mail template then check Laravel markdown, here you can change the default mail template:

if you do want to get HTML and be able to edit it, run this:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

This will happen:

> Copied Directory
>   [/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/resources/views] To
>   [/resources/views/vendor/mail]

Resource: https://laraveldaily.com/mail-notifications-customize-templates/

Answer (score 6):

I ended up using `Mail` facade in `User` model..

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token){
    // $this->notify(new MyCustomResetPasswordNotification($token)); <--- remove this, use Mail instead like below

    $data = [
        $this->email
    ];

    Mail::send('email.reset-password', [
        'fullname'      => $this->fullname,
        'reset_url'     => route('user.password.reset', ['token' => $token, 'email' => $this->email]),
    ], function($message) use($data){
        $message->subject('Reset Password Request');
        $message->to($data[0]);
    });
}
```

Comment: This helped me but you forgot to include `Mail` class `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;`. Thanks.

Comment: This works really well! Best solution by far!

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by building your own mail template and sending the Reset link yourself using the php `mail()` or or Laravel `Mail Facade` but first you will need to create the reset token

1) `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker;`

```
  $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
                 if ($user) {
                    //so we can have dependency 
                    $password_broker = app(PasswordBroker::class);
                    //create reset password token 
                    $token = $password_broker->createToken($user); 

                    DB::table('password_resets')->insert(['email' => $user->email, 'token' => $token, 'created_at' => new Carbon]); 

//Send the reset token with your own template
//It can be like $link = url('/').'/password/reset/'.$token;

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

in .env file or config/app.php file you have to change your app name and it's working fine.

Comment: This will change the text in the header, but not the template.