# Laravel, I cannot find out how to change reset email markdown

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am in the middle of a project using Laravels auth framework. I want to find out how to modify the default email that is sent. The default email looks like this...

[Image of email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc8j8.png)

There for some reason is a hash at the start of it, and cannot figure out why. I also want to change the markdown of the email, but cannot locate the files to do this.

Any help would be great.

I have tried `php artisan vendor:publish` but this has not worked. I saw this on a few threads but still couldn't find the answer.

Comment: how we can help you if you don't provide any code with your question ?

Comment: @AlaChebil Thats the issue I am having, I do not know what code is responsible for sending that email. Nor can I track it down.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mail check this link  to know how laravel send mails

Comment: Check the template files, and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/41401524/1427878